# Python - Access NumPy Array Item

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python for the first time in a long time and am slightly lost. I have a `numPy` array that looks like this when I print it..

```
   [[148 362]
     [153 403]
     [163 443]
     [172 483]
     [186 521]
     [210 553]
     [239 581]
     [273 604]
     [314 611]
     [353 602]]
```

I am trying to get the 5 item from the array and save it as 2 variables, x and y.

I have tried accessing it using...

```
print("Item 5" + numpy_array[5])
```

But that is giving me an error

```
typeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S21') dtype('S21') dtype('S21')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are other examples:

```
print("Item 5: " + str(numpy_array[5]) ) #=> Item 5: [210 553]

print("Item 5: ", numpy_array[5][0], numpy_array[5][1] ) #=> Item 5:  210 553

print("Item 5: ", numpy_array[5][0], "-" , numpy_array[5][1] ) #=> Item 5:  210 553

print (f"Item 5: {numpy_array[5][0]}, {numpy_array[5][1]}" ) #=> Item 5: 210, 553
```

Comment: Thanks for those, lots of different options,

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your array is stored in variable called `numpy_array`, just do. Since your subarrays contains 2 elements, it will unpack the values into x and y

```
x, y = numpy_array[5]
print (x, y)
# (210, 553)
```